# Need help writing a test class for a refresh action on a VF page

Tags: visualforce, code-coverage, method

I have created a VF Page Report for showing data based off of 2 dates.  The VF Page works great but I am unable to get the code coverage I need to deploy. Right now all but lines 17-18 and 24-34 are covered.  Pretty much the public void refresh() method.

VF PAGE

```
public class MonthlySeizureController1{
    public task taskRec                 { get; set; }
    public task taskRec1                { get; set; }
    public List<Case__c> theCases              { get; set; } // this was the ca reference
    public Map<Id, Business__c> businessMap   { get; set; } // this was the bus1 reference
    public MonthlySeizureController1(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        this();
    }
    public MonthlySeizureController1() {  
        taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today().addMonths(-1));
        taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today());
        // get the supply chain cases in the last month be careful of 10k cases in this result
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs); 
    }  
    public void refresh() {
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs);
    }

    public Map<Id, Business__c> queryBusinesses(Set<Id> businessIDs) { 
        Map<Id, Business__c> result =  new Map<Id, Business__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                    , Name
                                                                    , Business_Name__c
                                                                    , Business_Type__c
                                                                    , (SELECT Street__c
                                                                            , Business_City__c
                                                                            , State_Province__c
                                                                            , Country__c
                                                                            , Zip_Postal_Code__c 
                                                                        FROM BPR_Business_Addresses__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Number_Type__c
                                                                            , Number__c 
                                                                        FROM Business_Phone_Numbers__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Email_Bus__c 
                                                                        FROM Email_Businesses__r)
                                                                FROM Business__c
                                                                WHERE (Id = :businessIDs)]);
        return result;
    }
    public List<Case__c> querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(Date lowerDate, Date upperDate) { 
        List<Case__c> cases = [SELECT Id
                                    , Name
                                    , CreatedDate
                                    , Owner.FirstName
                                    , Owner.LastName
                                    , Notification_Date__c
                                    , Incident_City__c
                                    , Incident_Country__r.Name
                                    , Total_Product__c
                                    , Comments_Postal_Express__c
                                    , (SELECT RecordType.Name
                                            , CreatedDate
                                            , Container__c
                                            , Ship_Date__c
                                            , Date_of_Retention__c
                                            , Carrier__c
                                            , Port_of_Loading__c
                                            , Port_of_Discharge__c
                                            , Container_Type__c
                                            , Place_of_Retention__c
                                            , Vessel__c
                                            , Master_BOL__c
                                            , House_BOL__c
                                        FROM Incident_Locations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Brand__c
                                            , Product_Detail__c
                                            , Product_Types__c
                                            , Total_Product_Quantity__c 
                                        FROM Products__r)
                                    , (SELECT Business__c
                                            , Case__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Name__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Type__c 
                                        FROM BusinessCasesAssociations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c
                                            , Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c 
                                        FROM Subject_for_Cases__r)
                                FROM Case__c
                                WHERE Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
                                    AND Id IN (SELECT IL__c FROM Supply_Chains__c WHERE CreatedDate >= :lowerDate AND CreatedDate <= :upperDate)
                                ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
        return cases;
    }
    public PageReference next(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/MonthlySeizureReport1ppv');
        return nextpage;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class that I have written so far.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

UPDATED TEST CLASS 8/28/18

```
@isTest
public class MonthlySeizureController1Test {
public static testMethod void testMonthlySeizureController1() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.MonthlySeizureReport1; //replace with your VF page name
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 22);
    Date myDate1 = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 18);
    Date myDate2 = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 31);
    //Add test data. For example, create a set of test Opportunities
Case__c testCase = new Case__c(Case_Name__c = 'Test Case'
                                , Notification_Date__c = myDate
                                , Incident_City__c = 'Oruro'
                                , Incident_Country__c = 'a08C000000AIGaPIAX'
                                , Comments_Postal_Express__c = 'test comments'
                                ,Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
                                );
Supply_Chains__c testSupply = new Supply_Chains__c(RecordTypeId = '012C0000000cairIAA'
                                                    , Ship_Date__c = myDate
                                                    , Date_of_Retention__c = myDate
                                                    , IL__c = testCase.Id);
 Business__c testBus = new Business__c(Business_Name__c = 'Test Business'
                                , Business_Type__c = 'Exporter');
 BusinessCasesAssociation__c testBusCase = new BusinessCasesAssociation__c(Business__c = testBus.Id
                                        , Case__c = testCase.Id
                                        , How_are_the_business_and_case_related__c = 'Unknown'
                                        , Please_describe_the_relationship__c = 'test');
 Subject__c testSub = new Subject__c(First_Name__c = 'TestFirst'
                                , Last_Name__c = 'TestLast' 
                                , Subject_Type__c = 'Exporter');
 Subject_for_Case__c testSubCase = new Subject_for_Case__c(Case_Name__c = testCase.Id
                                 , Subject_Name__c = testSub.Id);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('taskRec', '2017-12-18');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('taskRec1', '2017-12-31');
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testcase);     
    MonthlySeizureController1 controller = new MonthlySeizureController1(sc);
    controller.refresh();
    //Test Data
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testCase);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testSub);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testBus);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testSubCase);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testBusCase);  
    System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.next()); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed Supply_Chain_Type__c='SEA' while inserting the Case. And you did not even called the refresh method.

Replace your test class with the following code

```
@isTest
public class MonthlySeizureController1Test {
public static testMethod void testMonthlySeizureController1() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.MonthlySeizureReport1; //replace with your VF page name
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 22);
    Date myDate1 = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 18);
    Date myDate2 = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 31);
    //Add test data. For example, create a set of test Opportunities
Case__c testCase = new Case__c(Case_Name__c = 'Test Case'
                                , Notification_Date__c = myDate
                                , Incident_City__c = 'Oruro'
                                , Incident_Country__c = 'a08C000000AIGaPIAX'
                                , Comments_Postal_Express__c = 'test comments'
                                ,Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
                                );
Supply_Chains__c testSupply = new Supply_Chains__c(RecordTypeId = '012C0000000cairIAA'
                                                    , Ship_Date__c = myDate
                                                    , Date_of_Retention__c = myDate
                                                    , IL__c = testCase.Id);
 Business__c testBus = new Business__c(Business_Name__c = 'Test Business'
                                , Business_Type__c = 'Exporter');
 BusinessCasesAssociation__c testBusCase = new BusinessCasesAssociation__c(Business__c = testBus.Id
                                        , Case__c = testCase.Id
                                        , How_are_the_business_and_case_related__c = 'Unknown'
                                        , Please_describe_the_relationship__c = 'test');
 Subject__c testSub = new Subject__c(First_Name__c = 'TestFirst'
                                , Last_Name__c = 'TestLast' 
                                , Subject_Type__c = 'Exporter');
 Subject_for_Case__c testSubCase = new Subject_for_Case__c(Case_Name__c = testCase.Id
                                 , Subject_Name__c = testSub.Id);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('taskRec', '2017-12-18');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('taskRec1', '2017-12-31');
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testcase);     
    MonthlySeizureController1 controller = new MonthlySeizureController1(sc);
    controller.refresh();
    //Test Data
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testCase);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testSub);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testBus);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testSubCase);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testBusCase);  
    System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.next()); 
}
```

}

Comment: that got all but 4 lines.  Can't believe I missed the refresh method.  Doh!  It looks like it is the same 2 lines of code on both of the methods, for (BusinessCaseAssociation__c bca...  Lines 17-18 and Lines 29-30.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much for the help on this!

Comment: ActivityDate__c is of type Date & while querying you are comparing with CreatedDate of type Datetime. SO the query is not returnig any results.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Can you provide some code to help me understand?  I will update the code above with your other recommendations. thx.

Comment: Can you check ActivityDate__c is of type Date or DateTime

if it is of DateTime Then Change the below 2 lines
taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today().addMonths(-1));
 taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today());
to
taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = DateTime.now().addMonths(-1));
 taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = DateTime.now());

Comment: Gotcha!  I updated the code so it is using a DateTime for the VF Page.  I am still unsure how to get those 4 lines of code to be covered.  If the query is not showing anything from the test class, could it be the parameters I am passing?  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('taskRec', '2017-12-18'); and ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('taskRec1', '2017-12-31');

Comment: Still need to get those last 4 lines, and ideas?